# Trying to select rows based on value from specific column in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) in r that has 200 columns and 18 rows.  The columns have names of people, and the rows names are years (formatted "X2015", "X2016", etc.).  The values in the data frame are the number of grades received by the individual in a certain year.  For example:

```
      Jen  Fred  Alex  John
X2010  55   265   436   409
X2011  54   261   456   417
X2012  54   263   494   415
X2013  52   253   526   419
X2014  52   250   556   426
```

I am trying to determine what years Alex received more than 500 grades.

So far, I have tried the following, none of which have worked:

```
subset(df,select="Alex", df$Alex>500)

df[df$Alex>500,]
```

Along with many variations of these.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
row.names(df)[df$Alex > 500]
```

or

```
row.names(df[df$Alex > 500,])
```

Both will return the row names that fulfill the condition that Alex got more than 500.
If you want to obtain only the number of the years (without the "X") do:

```
Xyear <- row.names(df[df$Alex > 500,])
year <- substring(Xyear,2)
```

Comment: When I enter this, r returns: character(0)

Comment: I'm getting character(0) if no values satisfy the condition (i.e. if all values are less than 500). Maybe this is your problem.